# xfce session always saved

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, desktop-environment

There are many posts here on U&L on the topic; Using `arch` + `xfce` + no display manager but the bug ([obviously](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7930)) keeps saving my sessions although `Automatically save session on logout` is unchecked.

What would be the best workaround? Right now I am thinking of `rm` the contents of `.cache/sessions` and `.xfce4-sessions` in `.xinitrc`.

**Update**

A simple one-liner solves the problem (the ugly way). The `.xinitrc`

```
rm -R ~/.cache/sessions
```

Comment: A hack would be to add a soft link to force XFCE never be able to write the session: `ln -s /dev/null/ ~/.xfce4-sessions`